# React router not redirecting in saga

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm using react & redux-saga

What I'm trying to accomplish is when I get 401 response from api, to redirect user to login page

```
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";

import {
  AUTH_LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
} from "constants";

export function* errorHandler(err) {

  if (err.message.includes("401")) {
    yield put({ type: AUTH_LOGOUT_SUCCESS });
    //   redirect user to another page    
   }
}
```

I have tried adding

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';    

yield put(push('/path-to-go'));
```

but its not working :/

Comment: `react-route-redux` is depracted. I would try replacing it with https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router

Comment: @MartinKadlec I tried with connected-react-router but its not working :/

Comment: I suspect some wrong setup of the router library. Make sure the `connectRouter` function is used properly to setup the reducers etc. I would also try to use the router otuside of sagas (e.g. running `store.dispatch(push('/foo'))` in the setup to see if it does something).

Comment: Also, what major versions of `react-router` and `history` are you using?